# How can I get the updated state with redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, react-redux

I have a react project and redux for state management. These are my actions.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  handleChange: (name, value) => { dispatch(handleChange(name, value)) },
  filterRooms: (rooms) => { dispatch(filterRooms(rooms)) }
});
```

I have to use these 2 method one by one.

```
this.props.handleChange(pets, true);  // handle changes
this.filterRooms();   // filtering with changing value

filterRooms = () => {
  let {rooms,pets} = this.props; // Here I should get pets === true but it's false.

  // filter by pets
  if (pets) {
    tempRooms = tempRooms.filter(room => room.pets === true);
  }

  this.props.filterRooms(tempRooms);
}
```

If I use setTimeout for second method thats ok but I think that's not a correct way.

```
this.props.handleChange(name, value);
setTimeout(() => {
   this.filterRooms();
}, 500);
```

Comment: I think what you need is a redux thunk, then call the filterRooms action creator from within the thunk.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that below two function run in sequence, one after another

```
this.props.handleChange(pets, true);  // handle changes
this.filterRooms();   // filtering with changing value
```

First dispatch changed value to Redux. And it is updated there (as sample with `setTimeout` works). But don't expect updated value from Redux will be immediately available to `this.filterRooms()`.

You have some Reactjs component. Reactjs component is essentially class or function. Then you wrap in in `connect`. So your code may look like this

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
    onChange: () => {
        this.props.handleChange(pets, true);  // handle changes
        this.filterRooms();   // filtering with changing value
    }
    // other staff
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component1)
```

Whats happens in React. It instantiate class `Component1`, then calls `connect` which in turn calls some methods of your class (i.e. `render()` or something else). `connect` also pass some values from Redux store to your component as props. Method of `Component1` is executed and may change Redux state (as it do in your sample). But updated props will not be immediately available. `props` are just arguments, that have been passed by `connect` function. To change arguments of any function, you should call it once again. So after receiving updated `pets`, `connect` will call your component again with updated `pets`. But it will be later.

`connect()` -> calls `Component1` and passes `props.pets = false` -> `Compoentn1` sets `pets` in Redux to `true` -> `connect()` receives updated `pets` and calls `Component1` with `props.pets = true`

That's why trick with `setTimeout` works. Ste timeout just await for second call of `Component1`

To solve your exact issue, don't read `pets` from `props` if you know that you've updated it.

```
this.props.handleChange(pets, true);  // handle changes
this.filterRooms(true);   // filtering with changing value

filterRooms = (pets) => {
  let {rooms} = this.props; 

  // filter by pets
  if (pets) {
    tempRooms = tempRooms.filter(room => room.pets === true);
  }

  this.props.filterRooms(tempRooms);
}
```